Hugging Face pipeline vs manual processing produces different embeddings for Vision Transformers
I am using the transformers library with the ViTForImageClassification model ('google/vit-base-patch16-224') to extract embeddings from images. However, I am observing different embeddings when I use the pre-built pipeline function compared to a manual extraction process, despite targeting the same model architecture and layer.

Are there any inherent differences in how the pipeline and manual methods handle image preprocessing or feature extraction that could lead to this discrepancy?

How can I ensure that the embeddings extracted from both methods are comparable?

Is there additional configuration in the pipeline function that might affect the output, which is not explicitly set in the manual approach?


# %% data
import requests
import torchvision
from PIL import Image

# url = "https://huggingface.co/datasets/Narsil/image_dummy/raw/main/parrots.png"

url = 'http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg'
pil_image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

embeddings = {}

# %% APPROACH 1
# note: prints warning: Some weights of ViTModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at google/vit-base-patch16-224 and are newly initialized ['vit.pooler.dense.bias', 'vit.pooler.dense.weight']
from transformers import pipeline

extractor = pipeline(model="google/vit-base-patch16-224", task="image-feature-extraction")
y = extractor(pil_image, return_tensors=True)

embeddings['transformers_pipeline'] = y

# %% APPROACH 2
from transformers import ViTImageProcessor, ViTForImageClassification

processor = ViTImageProcessor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224')
model = ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224',
                                                  output_attentions=False,
                                                  output_hidden_states=True)  # Enable outputting hidden

inputs = processor(images=pil_image, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
y = outputs.hidden_states[-1]

embeddings['transformers_base'] = y

